# How to do smooth automated zooming in on an image using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

On the front page of [our site](http://www.urbangolf.co.uk) using flash I have built a smooth zooming in to the image as you can see, where the focal point moves in and then stops after a few seconds.  I am wondering if there is a way to do this in JavaScript (ideally JQuery), as I would like to implement it later in the site but without flash...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Cheers,
Shadi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are many jQuery plugins that do this, and some do a lot more. I did a google search for "jquery zoom image" and this is the first thing that showed up that seemed to do the job:

http://www.eyecon.ro/zoomimage/

The other basic concept is using jQuery's `animate()` function that can make you animate the change in width and height. You would have to have a container over the image that has the CSS property `overflow: hidden`. This would allow you to expand the image to whatever dimensions you want.

Comment: None of the demos do the effect i am after?

Comment: Note the second half of my answer. The first is just a zoom effect, and after I looked at your website I realized you needed the second half.